# Is db_executor a standard role in SQL Server 2012 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2012, role

In trying to figure out the exact permissions I need to give a user to execute all stored procedures I ran across many pages saying to create a role of "db_executer" and give that role the `GRANT EXECUTE` permission, then assign users to that role. When I when to my sever to make that role I found out it already exists. Since I inherited this server I am not sure if it was made by the last admin, a program, or is a built in. Searching Google I am not finding any relevant hits newer then 2010 and those all talk about how to make the role. Can anyone tell me if this is a default role in 2012 or if someone/thing else made it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

db_executor is not a default role ([MS has a list of default roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121(v=sql.110).aspx)), it would have been created by somebody.

There's also no SQL Server 2012 R2. Potentially you are getting confused with Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Yea sorry, SP2 not r2. It is running on Windows Server 2012 R2 though. And thanks for the link.